# NetBeans version control for newb?

Tags: version-control, netbeans

I'm a relatively new programmer and I've never used version control before.  I'm working on a Java project in NetBeans and was wondering about some good version control options that are relatively easy to install and use.  Not sure if it matters, but I run OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Subversion was an easy solution for my project constraints.  The Subversion guide for NetBeans: http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html was especially useful in terms of walking me through both installation and basic use.

Answer (score 1):

On the menu if you go to Tools > Plugins, you can choose to install a plugin for whatever version control you're using.  I've got IDE 6.7 installed, and it comes with Subversion SVN, CVS, and Mercurial.

When I setup my NB project as an SVN repository, I did it first outside of NB with the 'svn' command.  Once set (it makes .svn folders everywhere) NetBeans automatically detected it and allows me to update/commit/all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Working on Mac OS X as well, with Netbeans 6.7 + SVN.

First thing to do is to create a new repository where all your files will be stored. This can be done using a GUI tool such as SVNx or through the command line :

```
svnadmin create REPOS_PATH
```

Once this is done, you're ready to import your project to the repository through the Netbeans interface ! If everything is set up in your netbeans, you should be able to right click a non-yet-version-controlled project and choose "Team > Import into SVN repository" or something like that (don't have NB right here to search for the right entry).

After that, if everything is alright, your project will be under the SVN version control. You can then do checkout to retrieve local working copy of the code, commit files, revert, etc...

Hope this helps !